# Magento2: TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I am getting the below error after applying the validation in my form:

> Magento2: TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined

Here is my validation code:

I have extended the customer address edit form, want to stop the default validation and added my custom validation.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $block */
 // 18id="form-validate"
?>
<?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company') ?>
<?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone') ?>
<?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax') ?>
<form class="form-address-edit"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
      id="validate-form"
      method="post"

      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="fieldset samefield_affecting">
        <legend class="legend block-title"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>

        <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getAddress()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getAddress()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend block-title"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
        <div class="field street">
            <label for="street_1" class="label">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address')) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="street[]"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine(1)) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address')) ?>"
                       id="street_1"
                       class="input-design input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>"/>
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                    <?php for ($_i = 1, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i < $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]"
                                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine($_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>"
                                       class="input-design input-text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
            <div class="field taxvat">
                <label class="label" for="vat_id">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('VAT Number')) ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="vat_id"
                           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('VAT Number')) ?>"
                           class="input-design input-text"
                           id="vat_id">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field city">
            <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="city"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                       class="input-design input-text"
                       id="city">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field region">
            <label class="label" for="region_id">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('State/Province')) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select id="region_id" name="region_id"
                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>"
                        class="select_img validate-select" <?= /* @noEscape */ !$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>>
                    <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text"
                       id="region"
                       name="region"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRegion()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>"
                       class="input-design input-text "<?= !$block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field zip">
            <label class="label" for="zip">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="postcode"
                       value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>"
                       id="zip"
                       class="input-design input-text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field country">
            <label class="label" for="country"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Country')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("It's a default billing address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set billing">
               <label class="submit_head phone_rig yes" for="primary_billing">
             <input class="input-design"  type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?> 
             <span class="submit_class"></span>
           </label>

            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("It's a default shipping address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set shipping">

               <label class="submit_head phone_rig yes" for="primary_shipping">
         <input class="input-design" type="checkbox" name="default_shipping" 
         id="primary_shipping" checked="checked" value="1"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default shipping address')) ?>
                 <span class="submit_class"></span>
               </label> 

            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary save_add">
            <button type="submit"
                    class="action submit primary save_width"
                    data-action="save-address"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
                 <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?> 
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<style type="text/css"> 
.fieldset>.field.required>.label:after, .fieldset>.fields>.field.required>.label:after, .fieldset>.field._required>.label:after, .fieldset>.fields>.field._required>.label:after {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px !important;
    top: 5px !important;
    position: relative;
}
.fieldset>.field .additional, .fieldset>.fields>.field .additional {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
div.mage-error[generated] {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
}
@media(max-width: 767px) {
.actions-toolbar,legend.legend.block-title {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
 }
  #country option:nth-child(3){ 
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function(jQuery)
{ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
      alert("Amy11");

        jQuery("#validate-form").validate(
        {
            rules: 
            {
                firstname: {
                    required:true
                },
                lastname: {
                   required:true
                },

                telephone: {
                   required:true
                }, 

               "street[]": {
                   required:true
                },  

                country_id: {
                   required:true
                },

                city: {
                   required:true
                },

                postcode: {
                   required:true
                },

            },
            messages: 
            {

                firstname: "Please enter your First Name",
                lastname: "Please enter your Last Name",
                telephone: "Please enter your Phone Number",
                "street[]": "Please enter your Street",
                country_id: "Please enter your Country",
                city: "Please enter your City",
                postcode: "Please enter your Zip/Postal Code",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form, event) 
            { 
                event.preventDefault();
                //console.log("aaaaaaaaaaa");
                form.submit();
             }
        });

    });

});

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: refer this if that's relevant to you 

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896205/validator-validator-methodsmethod-is-undefined**

Comment: I have referred the link, It is not relevant to my issue.

Comment: can please post your html code too?

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: i can't see your firstname and lastname filed in phtml?

Comment: @Amy: try below code which i have mentioned in answer section.

Comment: @Mohit: <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?> This line gets the firstname and lastname. After clearing the field the validation message is showing but while submitting the page loads and showing the error message and the default validation message.

Comment: @BalwantSingh: I have tried your code, not working for me.

Comment: do you think this `"street[]"`

`"street[]": {
                   required:true
                }, `

this code is true? i have doubt about it.

Comment: @Amy: can you please add your code here? how you implement my code in yours.

Comment: @Amy: can you try another soln which i have mentioned in comment of answer's section ?

Answer (score 0):

**try below code for form validation**

```
jQuery('#form_id').validation().validate;
var isValidated = jQuery('#form_id').validation('isValid');
if(isValidated) {
    //do your code here
}
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Comment: @amy : just replace you scirpt tag with below code and observe browser console:

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function(jQuery)
{ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#validate-form').validation().validate;
  var isValidated = $('#validate-form').validation('isValid');
     if(isValidated) {
   //do your code here
   console.log('Your form is valid now');
     } else {
   console.log('Your form is not valid yet');
  }
    });

});
</script>

Comment: I have tried this method only, Now showing this error message TypeError: $ is not a function and SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Comment: @Amy: in your case replace $ with jQuery

Comment: @Amy: try this 

<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function(jQuery)
{ 
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#validate-form').validation().validate;
  var isValidated = jQuery('#validate-form').validation('isValid');
     if(isValidated) {
   //do your code here
   console.log('Your form is valid now');
     } else {
   console.log('Your form is not valid yet');
  }
    });

});
</script>

Comment: I have already replaced with jQuery and it is showing SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Comment: I am very confused

Comment: @Amy: can you please post the screenshot of console error here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96608/discussion-between-balwant-singh-and-amy).